# Passenger error: Could not find rake-12.0.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I get this error when I run my application in browser. Running Rails + Passenger + Nginx. I've tried various steps but still error remains the same.

```
Could not find rake-12.0.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
  /root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:87:in `block in materialize'
  /root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:81:in `map!'
  /root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:81:in `materialize'
  /root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:159:in `specs'
  /root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:218:in `specs_for'
  /root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:207:in `requested_specs'
  /root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:109:in `block in definition_method'
  /root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:21:in `setup'
  /root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler.rb:101:in `setup'
  /root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/bundler-1.15.4/lib/bundler/setup.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:430:in `activate_gem'
  /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:297:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:435:in `running_bundler'
  /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:296:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Did you try `gem install rake -v='12.0.0'` ?

Comment: What is your `passenger_ruby` set to?

Comment: @Roshan yes I did run gem install rake -v='12.0.0'

Comment: @Camden passenger_ruby is set to : passenger_ruby /root/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@atl_rockville/wrappers/ruby

Comment: And when you installed rake, did you ensure the right gemset was active?

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: Here are the docs on rvm gemsets: https://rvm.io/gemsets/using

Comment: Thanks @Camden. My application is working now. Had to delete and reinstall /redeploy from scratch. Thanks all for your help.